# C# generic try catch method conversion

Tags: c#, generics, timeout, try-catch, timeoutexception

I'm working on a code base with multiple services that get Timeout Exceptions.

My idea was to create a generic method that takes in a service method as parameter and returns the method call.

My issue is that when I call this method and pass in a method that returns a list of int I get an error because it can't convert from `system.collections.generic.list...` to `system.func.system.collections.generic.list...`

I found a post which was trying to convert accordingly, but I don't wish to convert. I simply want the list of strings, not the function that gives me a list of strings. I'm not quite sure where to go from here?

```
private U HandleTimeoutException<U>(Func<U> fn)
{
  U result = default(U);

  try
  {
      result = fn();
  }
  catch (TimeoutException)
  {
      //some code that handles the exception
  };
  return result;
}
```

edit:

My method call is :

```
HandleTimeoutException<List<id>>(getListofIds(fName,lName,regionId));
```

I think that c# won't let me pass the method signature as parameter because the signature itself has 3 parameters, or because it evaluates the method and think it's getting a list of Id's as parameter. Is there anyway I can use a delegate to call getListofIds(X,Y,Z) and pass that delegate to my generic try/catch function?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The code you posted here should work.

Comment: Could it be the reason it's not working is because the methods i pass it have anywhere from 0-10 parameters? 

I was attempting a functional solution, where my method took in any method whatsoever, and just wrapped it in a try catch, but for some reason it doesn't work lol.

Comment: Could you post all the code required to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is not passing a function to `HandleTimeoutException`, but passing the result of `getListofIds` method.

This will fix it:

```
HandleTimeoutException(() => getListofIds(fName, lName, regionId));
```

Notice: you don't even have to specify the template argument type.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late approval of the answer, was in final exams.